# Sharepoint List migration

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

how to **migrate** all list and list data from one site to another site. List contains the calculated and lookup column

I have established Dev environment and I want to move all the site data
(ex. List ,libraries,workflows) to another site which is the Test environment. Please suggest the help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the really great things about SharePoint is that you can template a lot of the content and re-use it elsewhere. You can also create templates that include the contents of a site if you want.
You create the site template as you normally would be going into Site Settings for that site and then selecting Save site as a template.
Refer the Below link for Migrating the SharePoint Site from One to another

[Link 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033(v=office.15).aspx)

[Update Link](http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/07/using-site-template-with-new-site.html)

Comment: Please update your answer as the second link is broken.

Comment: Using the Site template for migration , lookup will break and also calculated column will be break

Comment: Lookup column is based on the list guid if it migrates, List guid definitely changes

Comment: Link Updated...

Answer (score 0):

just copy the calculated field formulae, while to migrate lookup column just follow the steps in 
[thislink](http://sharepointquicksolutions.blogspot.in/2012/07/migrating-list-which-contains-lookup.html)
after creating list in the target site collection, add one calculated column using copied formulae

Answer (score 0):

If you try to migrate all lists along with its data in a programmatic way, there are multiple folds to it, preserving the list template, its configurations and data. Eventually you'll end up in writing a standalone migration tool. You are already aware of cons of saving site as web template. Best of my knowledge is to use any ISV migration tools like ShareGate or Metalogix.

If you don't care about the data, then consider saving the site as PnP provisioning template and then create a site out of it in your target environment. Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/59066)

Comment: What made you think like that this not an appropriate answer? User never mentioned that, wants to achieve this programmatic on his question. Even if he chose that, its going to be equivalent effort of writing a standalone migration tool.

Comment: it is as per the SE policy, as your question is too short, also he can use backup the whole site collection...if you put more detail about your answer, that may help....Btw 3 people review it.

Comment: :-D Waqas- If you observe the question carefully its for SharePoint online, there is no way to backup a site collection without a ISV tools like what I proposed.

Comment: If u think this is not right decision, my dear u can dispute it...may be we are wrong. No worry

Comment: Thanks for the comments Waqas, no worries will provide more details.